# Updating a task on my website deletes a picture that the item contains - how do I fix this?

Tags: php, html, sql

PHP:

```
<?php

require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";
require "../modeli/zadatak.php";
require "../modeli/kategorija.php";

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["korisnik"])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_COOKIE["korisnik"])) {
    $korisnik = $_COOKIE["korisnik"];
}

if (isset($_POST["button2"])) {
    $zadatak = trim($_POST["zadatak"]);

    $podaci = Zadatak::vratiPodatke($zadatak, $konekcija);
    if ($podaci->slika != "") {
    unlink("../slike/".$podaci->slika);
    }
    Zadatak::obrisi($zadatak, $konekcija);
} else if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
    $zadatak = trim($_POST["zadatak"]);
    $naziv = trim($_POST["naziv"]);
    $kategorija = trim($_POST["kategorija"]);
    $opis = trim($_POST["opis"]);
    $izvrsen = trim($_POST["status"]);

    $provera = trim($_POST["provera"]);
    $obrisi = trim($_POST["obrisi"]);

    if ($provera != "") {
        $ime = "";
    }

    if ($_FILES["real_file"]["name"] != "") {
        $ime = time()."_".$_FILES["real_file"]["name"];
        $target = "../slike/".$ime;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["real_file"]["tmp_name"], $target);
    }
    
    Zadatak::izmeni($zadatak, $naziv, $kategorija, $opis, $izvrsen, $ime, $konekcija);
}

?>
```

The update function:

```
public static function izmeni($zadatak, $naziv, $kategorija, $opis, $izvrsen, $slika, mysqli $konekcija) {
        $datumZavrsetka = null;

        if ($izvrsen == "1") {
            $datumZavrsetka = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        if ($slika != "") {
            $dodaj = $konekcija->prepare("UPDATE zadatak SET naziv = ?, kategorija = ?, opis = ?, izvrsen = ?, datumZavrsetka = ?, slika = ? WHERE zadatakID = ?");
            $dodaj->bind_param("sisissi", $naziv, $kategorija, $opis, $izvrsen, $datumZavrsetka, $slika, $zadatak);
            $dodaj->execute();
        } else {
            $dodaj = $konekcija->prepare("UPDATE zadatak SET naziv = ?, kategorija = ?, opis = ?, izvrsen = ?, datumZavrsetka = ?, slika = NULL WHERE zadatakID = ?");
            $dodaj->bind_param("sisisi", $naziv, $kategorija, $opis, $izvrsen, $datumZavrsetka, $zadatak);
            $dodaj->execute();
        }
        return $dodaj;
    }
```

HTML and JQuery:

```
<div class="datadeo">
   <h4>Naziv</h4>
   <input type="text" id="naziv" name="naziv" value ="<?=$podaci->naziv?>">

<h4>Kategorija</h4>
<select id="kategorija" name="kategorija"></select>

<h4>Opis</h4>
<textarea name="opis" id="opis"><?=$podaci->opis?></textarea>
</div>

<div class="datadeo1">
    <h4>Slika</h4>
    <?php if($podaci->slika == "") { ?>
        <div id="slikadiv">
            <input type="file" name="real_file" id="real_file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" value="" hidden="hidden">
            <button type="button" id="custom_button" class="inputslika">Izaberi sliku</button>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id = "slikawrapnad" class="slikawrapnad">
            <div class="slikawrap1">
                <img id="slicica" src="../slike/<?=$podaci->slika?>"/>
            </div>
            <input type="file" name="real_file" id="real_file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" value="" hidden="hidden">
            <button type="button" id="custom_button" class="inputslika1"><span class="puntekst">Izmeni sliku</span><span class="krataktekst">Izmeni</span></button>
            <button type="button" id="custom_button1" class="inputslika2" onclick="resetujFormu();"><span class="puntekst">Obriši sliku</span><span class="krataktekst">Obriši</span></button>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <h4>Status</h4>
    <div class = "status">
        <input type="radio" id="neizvrsen" name="status" class="opcija" value="0">
        <label for="neizvrsen">Neizvršen</label>
        <input type="radio" id="izvrsen" name="status" class="opcija" value="1">
        <label for="izvrsen">Izvršen</label>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonwrapperizmena">
        <div class="buttoncontainerizmena">
            <button type="submit" class="buttonizmena" name="button" onclick="izmeniZadatak();"><span class="puntekst">Izmeni zadatak</span><span class="krataktekst">Izmeni</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttoncontainerizmena">
            <button type="submit" class="button2izmena" name="button2" onclick="obrisiSliku(); obrisiZadatak();"><span class="puntekst">Obriši zadatak</span><span class="krataktekst">Obriši</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>

<input type="text" value="" id="provera" name="provera" hidden="hidden">
                <input type="text" value="" id="obrisi" name="obrisi" hidden="hidden">

</div>

<script>
function izmeniZadatak() {
    $("#formaizmena").ajaxForm(function() {
        $("#prikaziizmeni").css("display", "flex");
        popuniZadatke();
        $("#skriveno").css('display', 'none');
    })
}

</script>
```

The form works fine when deleting a task - if it has an image, it will remove the task and the image, and if not, it will just remove the image. The form works fine when it has to upload a new picture, change an existing one or remove an existing one. But the problem occurs when I try to update it without doing anything to the picture in the task. It always ends up dissappearing (the database field shows up as NULL) no matter what I do and I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me out?

Comment: At the moment your SQL query sets`slika = NULL` when there is no image uploaded. I think it should just not write anything for that column at all in the query, so that it remains unchanged.

Comment: @ADyson Can you help me out with where to change it? I'm kind of lost

Comment: I literally just told you what to change - remove the `slika = NULL` from the query

Comment: @ADyson My apologies, I made it more complicated in my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
UPDATE zadatak SET naziv = ?, kategorija = ?, opis = ?, izvrsen = ?, datumZavrsetka = ?, slika = NULL WHERE zadatakID = ?
```

to

```
UPDATE zadatak SET naziv = ?, kategorija = ?, opis = ?, izvrsen = ?, datumZavrsetka = ? WHERE zadatakID = ?
```

i.e. you must remove the

```
slika = NULL
```

part so that it does not overwrite the image data with `NULL` when nothing new has been uploaded. If you simply remove this from the `UPDATE` query, the existing value in that column will remain and will not be changed.